# ASP.NET MVC 4 FilePathResult and staticfile handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I'm building a simple CMS for one B2B application. The user can upload/browse an image, but those images are stored outside of IIS (my application is located on drive C, and images are stored on drive D).

My plan is to create a custom route for page files, and then simply load images using `FileController`

FileController:

```
public FilePathResult PageFiles(string fileName)
{
    var dir = Server.MapPath("/some_protected_area/gallery");
    var path = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
    return File(path, "image/jpg");
}
```

Custom route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "Files/PageFiles/{fileName}",
    new { controller = "File", action = "PageFiles", fileName = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "DemoApp.Web.Controllers" }
    );
```

When I access `http://localhost:58891/Files/PageFiles/image-1.jpg` I get 404.

Detailed Error Information:

```
Modeule: IIS Web Core
Notification: MapRequestHandler
Handler: StaticFile
Error code: 0x80070002
```

When I access: `http://localhost:58891/Files/PageFiles?fileName=image-1.jpg` everything works fine, but I don't want to send `fileName` in query string, and `fileName` **must** contain the extension (.jpg, .pdf, etc.)

Can I somehow disable `StaticFile` handler for custom routes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can I somehow disable StaticFile handler for custom routes?

Of course, just add the following handler to the `<handlers>` section of your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <handlers>
        ...
        <add 
            name="MyImageHandler" 
            path="Files/PageFiles/*" 
            verb="GET" 
            type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
            preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" 
        />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

What this handler does is to intercept all requests to `Files/PageFiles/*` and pass them to the managed ASP.NET pipeline for serving. Thus they will reach the desired `FilesController`. Without this handler IIS thinks that the request is for a static file (since it ends with `.jpg`) and completely bypasses the managed execution attempting to serve the file directly.

And by the way this `Server.MapPath` function that you are using in your controller action won't work for files stored outside of your web application folder.

Remark: You might see other responses suggesting you to set `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` but I would totally recommend against this approach as this will make ALL requests to ALL static files going through the managed pipeline which might have a negative performance effect on your application. It is far more efficient to enable this only for the route you want to handle (`Files/PageFiles/*`).

Comment: That's true but I prefer explicitly enabling this only for the route I need to support rather than jeopardizing the performance of my entire application.

Comment: I agree with your logic in general, but performance hit is not "jeopardizing" as you claim. It does add some overhead. MS would not add feature that "cripples" application in the first place, right?

Comment: Sure, but why adding this overhead? IIS static handler is best at serving static files such as javascript, css, images, ... I really don't want this to go through the entire managed pipeline. I don't want to argue with you. I respect your opinion on this subject. I just expressed mine so that people are aware about the consequences of using your solution since you missed that in your answer. Your answer is good and it will work, it's just that it is missing this important detail.

Comment: But if he wants to remap external folder, changes routing inside of his app, or make any code decision, he cannot do it.

Comment: Sure he can. He just need to update his web.config. By the way you could register handlers dynamically. So this handler could be dynamically registered along with your routes, in exactly the same place, using exactly the same pattern. This way there will be no code duplication and if you change your route it will immediately reflect on the handler. With 0 efforts and hassle.

Comment: That would still solve only routing part and already adds complexity. No code decisions, and now will he pull in file outside of the physical folder that is mapped in the handler config?

Comment: I don't really see what does the actual physical location of the file has to do with this. Are you suggesting that he moves the files inside his application root and completely get rid of the controller to serve them? That would indeed be a good approach.

Comment: It was in the question. He wants to remap external folder in the route path.

Comment: No, he is not mapping any external folder. This is absolutely impossible. What he is trying to do is to map an ASP.NET MVC controller that has the filename as part of the path portion of the route. The fact that this controller is serving files from an external location or doing something else is not the problem here. The problem is how to prevent IIS from intercepting this request and using the StaticHandler instead.

Comment: And... return files that are not physically on that path. Exactly.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are arguing about here. I am sorry. What's your point? We both showed 2 different approaches of solving the same problem. Each having its advantages and drawbacks. Let's leave now the decision to the OP. Neither I will convince you that my solution is better neither you will convince me that your solution is better. End of the story.

Comment: I'm arguing that handler approach doesn't solve use-case in the question.

Comment: You are saying that my solution with registering the handler in web.config won't work?

Comment: Not for use-case originally described.

Comment: The use case originally described is to have a request such as `http://example.com/Files/PageFiles/image-1.jpg` being served by the `PageFiles` action on the `Files` controller. That's exactly what my solution illustrates on how to achieve. Yours as well by the way. The fact that this controller action is serving files from an external location is not the point. The point is that the user is getting 404 and the controller action is never reached. That was the original problem. If you do not understand or admit that then you probably didn't understand the question, which would surprise me ...

Comment: And you are bypassing MVC and controller completely in your answer, serving files directly. yes. Plus, you did not address part where he says that he want's to serve files from another drive.

Comment: NOOOOO, you misunderstood my answer!!! What I am doing in my answer is bypassing IIS static handler

Comment: So maybe you should add configuring of VirtualPath in your answer.

Comment: No my friend. No. What my answer does is to bypass the IIS StaticHandler which was intercepting the request and telling it to pass it to the desired ASP.NET MVC controller. No I understand where your confusion comes from - you didn't understand what my answer do at all.

Comment: Hmm... then add in the answer what is happening there! :) (Instead of addressing other peoples answer.)

Comment: Isn't that obvious? In ASP.NET when you register a handler for a given path in your web.config this handler executes for the specified route. In my example the `TransferRequestHandler` is passing the execution to the managed pipeline for the `Files/PageFiles/*` path. I thought that was so obvious that didn't include it in my answer. Sorry if it wasn't for you. I will update my answer to include this information.

Comment: See, answer is more clear now. I really misinterpreted 1st version. Even with path configured in web.config this is worthy answer.

Comment: Only issue I found with this answer is Range/partial/206 requests, particularly sometimes when chrome is handling a video download, fail with MVC actions because they don't support these requests out of the box.  Using above web.config and in action when I was done with what my action needed to do, I used `Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Server.TransferRequest(fileUrl);` which essentially passes back to the static file handler so it can do its thing with range support.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I have followed the same method in my application. I do have a subfolder named Files then folder inside named PageFiles and then a pdf file inside that , But when I try to access that one using url its keep on giving me internal server error . Its not even going through MVC pipeline. Anyhelp ?

Answer (score 2):

I answered something similar few days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949459/dynamic-routing-with-web-api/), but basically:

Your path has to use wildcard `{*fileName}`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "Files/PageFiles/{*fileName}",
    new { controller = "File", action = "PageFiles", fileName = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new[] { "DemoApp.Web.Controllers" }
    );
```

And, to bypass StaticFile handler you have to change web config like this:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Btw, there are some answers suggesting that you use `TransferRequestHandler` instead of `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`, which is valid approach, but any case you have to fix the route.